# Why do I have to separate the <intent-filter> to show the "open" button on google play?

Tags: android, google-play, manifest

I have an app on GooglePlay, but the *Open* button is missing. It just says *Uninstall*.

This is my mainfest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name=".preview_refresh"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.url.com"
                    android:path="/launch"
                    android:scheme="https" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
   
    </application>
```

I figured out, the problem is:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

But I have these lines in my code. When I remove:

```
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.url.com"
                    android:path="/launch"
                    android:scheme="https" />
```

the *open* button is shown.

**How can I fix it? I need these tags to open my app via link.**

### EDIT

I solved my problem, but now I have a new question:

**Why do I have to separate the `<intent-filter>`? It's very confusing, because it shouldn't make any difference.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I figured it out. The solution is to separate the `<intent-filter>`. Like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Login_Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.urlk.com"
                    android:path="/launch"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```